# Why update statement doesn't execute?

Tags: postgresql

```
update movies 
    set title = 'new title',
        show_start = '16-04-2017',
        show_end = '16-04-2017' 
where id = 1;
```

It doesn't give any errors. But I waited 2 minutes and this statement did nothing. Select, insert and delete statements work just fine. Table has only 1 row.

Comment: Are you sure that the 'ID' value is '1'? and the datatype of ID is numeric?

Comment: @ShreyasSG yes. Select * from movies returns 1 row with id = 1

Comment: can you try with quotes? ie., ID = '1'

Comment: What do you mean with "did nothing"? Did your SQL client "hang" or did it return immediately reporting that no rows were updated?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name SQL client "hang"

Comment: @ShreyasSG it worked! Thanks

Comment: If the client hangs (=is waiting) then it's probably waiting for a lock. You can check that from a second session. Queries to check that are available in the  Postgres wiki: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Lock_Monitoring @ShreyasSG: that is a bad advice. If `id` is a number, you should **not** compare that with a string value

Comment: @SergeyKunitsyn it worked because the datatype for ID is defined as String instead of number. You may alter the table if required.
Nonetheless my solution worked. So, please be kind enough to accept the answer below :)

Comment: Changing the data type for the comparison will **not** change the behaviour of the client "hanging". There must be something else going on. If ID really was defined as `varchar` then `id = 1` would have resulted in a **error** ("operator does not exist: character varying = integer") not in the update doing "nothing"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the datatype is defined as string instead of number.
Try with single quotes.
ie., ID = '1'

```
update movies 
    set title = 'new title',
        show_start = '16-04-2017',
        show_end = '16-04-2017' 
where id = '1';
```

Comment: This can't be the solution. If `id` really was defined as `varchar` (or `text`)  then `where id = 1` would have resulted in an error ("operator does not exist: character varying = integer") **not** in the update doing nothing.